# Как записать "Харцызск" с помощью МФА?

Tags: фонетика, транскрипция, названия

Название города происходит от "харцыз". Неясно как передать "-зск". [Вот](https://youtu.be/PWkP-L9WZzo) пример местного произношения названия.

Comment: Чего ж неясного-то?  Просто "-ск" и всё тут... "З" оглушается перед "с".  Две фонемы "с" произносятся как одна.  "К" никуда не делась.

Comment: Обнаруженный Архангельск пишется через "z": [ ˈɑːkeɪnʤlzk ] http://myefe.ru/anglijskaya-transkriptsiya/arkhangelsk

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, вопрос: произношение слова на каком языке вы хотите передать в международной транскрипции? Видимо, не все думают, что на русском.

Answer (score 1):

Khartsyzk (украиноязычное написание) или Khartsyzsk (русскоязычное написание — встречается чаще).

[С форума](http://www.govorimpro.us/%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2-green-card-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8-dv-2013/32383-4-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-city-born-5.html).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или другие примеры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P. S. Так как Харцызска в английских словарях не наблюдается, для вычисления транскрипции нужно идти методом подобия. Чем нам плох для передачи окончания Архангельск, например?

[ˈɑːkeɪnʤlzk]

Нашла Норильск [nɔːˈrɪlsk]...

См. [Русско-английский географический словарь](http://geography_ru_en.enacademic.com/), [Транскрипция, произношение и перевод английских слов онлайн](http://myefe.ru/anglijskaya-transkriptsiya.html), а также ЦУ к

[***Просветите по поводу «перевода» топонимов!***](http://yermolovich.ru/board/1-1-0-610)

---

С [форума](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=4&MessNum=257206&l1=1&l2=2):

> Географические названия можно переводить и транскрипцией (передача
>   звучания слова), и транслитерацией (передача написания слова).

Comment: Чтой-то я не усмотрел МФА в Вашем ответе...

Comment: А я его специально от Вас спрятала. Картинка, где Khartsyzsk взят в прямоугольник, и есть искомый тугамент. Автор вопроса разбёрётся.

Comment: Могу только одно сказать: "Huh?!"

Comment: Не мытьём, так катанием... https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82

Comment: Ну а что Вы хотите? Нет квадратных скобок на клавиатуре - рисуем квадратики ))). Объяснять, что такое МФА, после такой живописи  уже как-то и не к лицу...

Answer (score 0):

ЗСК может передаваться как **[sk]** или как **[s:k]**, но обычно долготу, да еще неочевидную, у согласных не обозначают.

Comment: Это да. Но я не уверен, что украинское произношение точно соответствует русскому даже в стандарте МФА.